# Correct notation for product of each combination

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, notation

I am trying to create a square matrix $M$ that when you multiply it with another square matrix $A$ the result gives a diagonal with $0$'s. I have figured that a this can be done in a $3$ by $3$ matrix as follows:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-2bc & -2ef & -2hi \\
ac & df & gi \\
ab & de & gh
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & x_1 & x_2 \\
x_3 & 0 & x_ 4 \\
x_5 & x_ 6 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then I tried applying what I did there for an $n$ by $n$ matrix however I am unsure of the notation I need to describe the pattern. Right now I know that the j column of $M$ has every combination of pairs from the $j$ row of $A$ and in row 1 all the values are multiplied by $(1-n)$ however I don't know how that can be written.

Comment: First row, second column: $-2de$ should be $-2ef$

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to write it. Let $A$ be the matrix you're trying to transform and $M$ be your chosen square matrix. Then
$$M_{ij} = (1 - n\delta_{i, 1})\displaystyle\prod_{k\neq i}^{n}A_{jk}$$
where $\delta_{j, k}$ is the Kronecker delta. The $i$th row and $j$th column of $M$ is calculated by computing the product of all terms in the $j$th row of $A$  *except* the term in the $i$th column. For the first row of $M$ we multiply by $(1-n)$.